# Configuring Keras to use Tensorflow instead of Theano

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conda

I'm trying to configure Keras install under an Anaconda virtualenv with all of that running under Ubuntu 17.04. I've installed `keras-gpu` via `conda`, and have generated a bootstrap `~/.keras` directory by running `python -c 'import keras'`; finally, I've updated my `keras.json` within that directory to include `tensorflow` as the backend rather than `theano`.

I've also tried those steps with the regular, non-GPU `keras` available on `conda`.

The issue I'm getting is that the `backend` option in my `keras.json` is being read (since invalid values raise exceptions), but is being overruled by an environment variable that gets `export`ed by Anaconda itself -- according to `grep`, there are a few instances of:

```sh
export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
export KERAS_BACKEND=theano
```

... Scattered around a number of files in `~/miniconda3/pkgs/keras-2.0.2-py36_1/`.

I'm hesitant to manually edit these files since they're automatically put there by the package manager, but I also want to avoid explicitly specifying `KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow` at the start of each session, and I'd like to avoid solutions involving tools like `direnv`.

How can I get `conda`'s `keras` to use `tensorflow` by default?

Comment: Interesting.... A configuration that worked well for me was creating a virtual environment with conda with python `3.5`, and install the tensorflow-gpu using pip, and keras using conda. This worked pretty well, and the GPU is working well too. (It was Ubuntu 16.04) --- But if using jupiter, be careful, even if you install it in the environment, there is a chance that it still tries to load packages from outside, which is a lot of pain.

Comment: You can always launch your script like: `env KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow python my_keras_script.py`. Anaconda and `virtualenv` are two different tools, are you using both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in the file `activate.sh` of the [keras package](https://github.com/conda-forge/keras-feedstock/tree/master/recipe) **on conda-forge**. The `export` statements in this file are unnecessary and should be removed IMO. There's just no reason to restrict linux users to use theano as Keras backend (or TensorFlow for Mac OSX).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]
then
    # for Mac OSX
    export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
elif [ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]
then
    # for Linux
    export KERAS_BACKEND=theano
fi
```

You could solve the problem by:

1. Removing those environment settings from activate.sh.
2. Removing currently installed `keras` and `keras-gpu`, and then
   install keras with `conda install -c defaults keras`: the
   non-conda-forge version of keras seems to be okay. I didn't find any of those env settings on my machine.
3. `pip install keras`: removing currently installed `keras` and `keras-gpu`, and then install the python package only.

Comment: Using `pip install keras tensorflow-gpu` did the trick. Thanks!