# Keras: switching to new environment set backend to theano

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, theano

I currently do my work with keras using tensorflow as a backend. I recently created a conda environment to experiment with the multi-gpu facilities of keras 2.0.9, using python 3.5.3 and tensorflow-gpu 1.4.0. In that new environment keras consistently uses Theano as a backend.

I checked `~/.keras/keras.json`, the backend is set to `tensorflow`. However when I `source activate` to this new environment I see that the `KERAS_BACKEND` environment variable is set to `theano`. Setting it back to `tensorflow` works. However, I do not understand this automatic setting to theano. I have created more environments and all use tensorflow by default because I have never installed theano in the first place, nor have I in this newly created environment. Has something changed in 2.0.9? I could not find any `keras.json` in the anaconda directory.

Does anyone know how to prevent variable `KERAS_BACKEND` to theano when sourcing to the new environment?

**Edit**

@Yu Yang pointed to the user with a similar problem. The answer was to reinstall or to change the file `activate.sh`. I did the last (see below) but still theao is returned as `KERAS_BACKEND`.

```
$ cat bin/anaconda3/pkgs/keras-2.0.9-py35_0/info/recipe/activate.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]
then
    # for Mac OSX
    export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
elif [ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]
then
    # for Linux
    # export KERAS_BACKEND=theano
    export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
fi
```

Comment: Although under a different Keras version, your question looks quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46572361/1531463). There's a problem in the conda keras package, and it seems that it's not solved yet.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the suggestion of changing activate.sh (see edit). That did not work. I will see whether reinstalling is an option.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are using conda environments. I had the same problem and had to update `activate.sh` file in my anaconda tensorflow environment. But in your edit, you are editing this file in anaconda package path, but you should modify .sh file in your conda environment path (because this one is used when you do `activate`):

```
<path_to_conda>/envs/<env_name>/etc/conda/activate.d/keras_activate.sh
```

So in my case it was something like this:

```
$HOME/.conda/envs/tf_env/etc/conda/activate.d/keras_activate.sh
```

Check this [comment](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6925#issuecomment-335592597) in the discussion right in the keras github.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I kinda 'solved' my problem by `export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow` in `.bashrc`. Your suggestion seems to be better. I'll try it next week when I am behind my DL machine.